# Why double.MaxValue output has different maximum length with double max = 1.79769313486232E307;

Tags: c#, precision

I tried the following code to get maximum value of double (64-bit double-precision):

```
    public void double_max_value() {
        double max_value = double.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine(max_value.ToString());
    }
```

The results was:
[console output of double.MaxValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO5kv.png)

Then i tried to declare a variable:

```
double var_double = 1.79769313486232E+308;
```

I got an error: 
Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'double'.

It will work when i declare:

```
double var_double = 1.79769313486232E+307;
```

I'm using VS community 2015.
.NET framework version 4.7.03056.

Why do i got an error?since double.MaxValue output is 1.79769313486232E+308.
Thank you.

Comment: `Console.Write(double.MaxValue.ToString("R"));` (note `R` for round trip formatting) returns `1.7976931348623157E+308` - actual `double.MaxValue` value; `double.MaxValue.ToString()` rounds the value (and thus add round up errors)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I've tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you.

Comment: That decimal string needs to be converted to binary, from base 10 to base 2.  The end result is not *exactly* the same as double.MaxValue.  It can't be the same, the mathematically correct value has an infinite number of digits in base 10.  Or to put it another way, what you see in the console when you use double.MaxValue is *rounded*.  It got rounded up, that made the decimal value a wee bit too large.  Well, ~1E292 is not exactly wee.  Manipulating such massive numbers just isn't very sensible, be sure to write sensible code.